# Does Hibernate multi tenancy overhead while switching DataSources and selecting schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

In below given code i'm trying to change datasource and schema on the basis of tenantIdentifier.

eg:

```
@Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup(JNDI_NAME);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = selectDataSource(tenantIdentifier).getConnection();
        try {
            connection.createStatement().execute("select now()");
            connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + tenantIdentifier);
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Error trying to alter schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

Comment: No, it just cast connection to the specific tenant. It is pretty simple

Comment: But it will hit database???

Comment: Did you hear about idle connections and connection pool?
Anyhow it is unclear what you are asking, you are asking about hibernate and now about hitting database. :/

Comment: what make sense hear for idle connection or connection pooling...its simple that in case of multi tenancy if i switch database/schema then it will be overhead around ms....Please avoid comment before research effort/analysis because they seems useless...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor overhead (in ms) during switching DataSource and schema.